# loop to resample a combination of two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set of 16 rows and for each row I have a distance and a bearing from a specific location.
I want to construct a loop that randomly generates new 16 combinations of the distance and the bearing from the values I have in the original data. I want to do that many many times, maybe 1000 times. So that in the end I will have 1000 16 different combinations of those too values.

Anyone has any idea how to do that? 
I apologize for not including my data, this is my first time using this site and couldn't figure out how to neatly add the data on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If your data frame is called `df` and has columns called `bearing` and `distance`, then you could use

```
sample_df <- data.frame(bearing  = sample(df$bearing,  16, replace = TRUE), 
                        distance = sample(df$distance, 16, replace = TRUE))
```

to create a single data frame, or

```
f <- function(x) data.frame(bearing  = sample(df$bearing,  16, replace = TRUE), 
                            distance = sample(df$distance, 16, replace = TRUE))
lapply(seq(1000), f)
```

to get a list of 1000 different sampled data frames